# Excel - How to conditionally lock and unlock a particular cell using VBA.

Tags: vba, excel, locking, conditional-formatting

Title says it all. Any insight here? This code is most definitely not working:

```
Sub MrFreeze(ByVal Target As Range)

 Dim cCell As Range
 Dim wksInput As Worksheet

 Set wksInput = Worksheets("Input")
 Set cCell = wksInput.Range("D14")

 If cCell.Value = "Yes" Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password = "password"
    Else
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password = "password", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
 End If

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: "Not working" means what *exactly*?  Maybe you're missing the `:=` after `Password` (you just have `=`)

Comment: It is not unprotecting the worksheet when cell D14 changes. Tried your changes, its still not working. Any more advice? 

Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling this sub?  A little more detail wouldn't harm here...

Comment: I could be wrong but I guess you want to do `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Target.Parent.Name).Unprotect Password:="password"` instead of `Activesheet`?

Comment: @ Tim I am very new to programming (see: 2 days). Should this not be a sub? I am reading about event procedures right now, it seems like this would be better suited there?

@Siddharth, Ive just tried your solution, no dice there either.

Comment: Why do you have `ByVal Target As Range` in your Sub? Did you not write the code? Like Tim said, please provide more details?

Comment: I did not write this code, I have tried to modify the code of someone else. The original can be seen here, courtesy of Joe4 - http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/477560-conditional-locked-cells.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cell **D14** contains *Yes* and the macro is run, the cell will be unlocked.
If cell **D14** does not contains *Yes* and the macro is run, the cell will be locked.

```
Sub MrFreeze()

   Dim cCell As Range
   Dim wksInput As Worksheet

   Set wksInput = Worksheets("Input")
   Set cCell = wksInput.Range("D14")

   If cCell.Value = "Yes" Then
      ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password = "password"
         cCell.Locked = False
      ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password = "password"
   Else
      ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password = "password"
         cCell.Locked = True
      ActiveSheet.Protect Password = "password"
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Gary, this is amazing to me. Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisWilliamson  The key issue is to un-protect the sheet to change the lock status of any cells and then to re-protect the sheet.

Comment: Do you really want to repeat a password across all code? Also, using `SomeSheet.Protect Password:=constPW, UserInterFaceOnly:=True` allows any cell to be changed by code without unprotecting. There is a glitch where it needs to be reapplied on workbook open but is better than unprotect/protect everywhere.